# How can I style grid layout in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a carousel and below it I want to display 3 grids but they are overlapping. How can I style the grids so that they don't overlap.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="main-content">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>
            <h3>Enter title of news</h3>
            <p>your news description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>
            <h3>Enter title of news</h3>
            <p>your news description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>
            <h3>Enter title of news</h3>
            <p>your news description</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In css :

```
#main-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 800px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please put your working demo on fiddle? it will help you get quick and better solution.

Comment: @SonalKhunt check it I have attached screenshot.

Comment: try adding this css, may be its floating issue,

.row{ float:none; clear:both;}

Comment: @SonalKhunt I tried that but then it shrinks see-> http://imgur.com/a/2z7uf

Comment: Remove this css and add below line above <div id="main-content">,

<br clear='all' />

Comment: or try this linne, <br style="clear:both;" />

Comment: @SonalKhunt I have tried that line above div main-content still nochange

Comment: do you have live URL? where I can check using firebug to resolve this?

Comment: @SonalKhunt why can't I just use top:500px why does it shrinks.

Comment: @SonalKhunt No sorry I am doing a personal project in sublime.

Comment: @SonalKhunt what should I check in firebug tell me I will check it.

Comment: That way you cant do debug, have you removed your style while trying mine? I mean top & position? remove once and try clear. If proper HTML is written, clear should work. position might be causing issue.

Comment: @SonalKhunt I have changed the HTML code see-> http://imgur.com/a/9jfo9 Now it works why? I have also given `position:absolute` and `top:550px` so now it works fine should I remove div id='main-content' and change it to only container.

Comment: Yes try replacing main-content with container but container is class if you check. in bootstrap container meas 1170px. it will again shrink your content to 1170 which happen by applying my first css

Comment: Thanks, but have you resolved it? if yes then I can add my answer. so far I was suggesting you solution as i do not have code and trial to give perfect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I think this is what you're asking: you want the navbar, below that a carousel, and below that 3 "grids" side by side, not overlapping? This should work, if you insert it after the code for your navbar:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12>
            <!-- CODE FOR CAROUSEL -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <!-- GRID 1 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <!-- GRID 2 -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <!-- GRID 3 -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```